# Delete non number containing braces from string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

A string may contain non-number in braces which needs to be deleted. Input can be multiline too, for example :
**input:**

```
# (1437)  
# {19} (917) (1437)  
# {19} (1437) [1449] [2474] [2098] [1351] [508]   [969]( MONDAY) [sunday]
```

**desired output:**

```
# (1437)  
# {19} (917) (1437)  
# {19} (1437) [1449] [2474] [2098] [1351] [508] [969]
```

However the below regex instead of removing just ( MONDAY) [sunday] removes the last line completely.

```
$re = '/^(#\h*)((\[\d+]|\{\d+}|\(\d+\))(?:\h+(?3))*)$/m';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
echo implode("\n", array_map(fn($x) => $x[1] . implode(' ', array_unique(explode(' ', $x[2]))), $matches));
```

Comment: Try `preg_replace('~\s*(?:\[(?!\d+])[^][]*]|\((?!\d+\))[^()]*\)|\{(?!\d+)[^{}]*})~', '', $str)`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pFhTNS/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php (PCRE) flavor you may use this regex with conditional construct:

```bash
(?:(\()|({)|\[)\D*(?(1)\)|(?(2)}|]))\s*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gsbREw/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `(\()`: Match `(` and capture in group #1
  - `|`: OR
  - `({)`: Match `{` and capture in group #2
  - `|`: OR
  - `\[`: Match a `[`
- `)`: non-capture group
- `\D*`: Match 0 or more non-digits
- `(?(1)\)`: If group #1 is present then match `)`

  - `|`: OR
  - `(?(2)}|])`: If group #2 is present then match `}` else match `]`
- `)`: End of conditional construct
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces

**Code:**

```php
$r = preg_replace('/(?:(\()|({)|\[)\D*(?(1)\)|(?(2)}|]))\s*/', '', $s);
```

---

A bit more efficient version of above regex (avoids backtracking):

```bash
(?:(\()|({)|\[)(?(1)[^)\d]*\)|(?(2)[^}\d]*}|[^]\d]*]))\s*
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/gsbREw/2)

Comment: Can you ans this plz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73296237/removing-everything-except-numbers-inside-braces-and-some-characters

Comment: sure thing, checking