# Removing everything except numbers inside braces and some characters

Tags: php, regex

Want to remove everything except # NewLine, complete bracket set and numbers inside braces.
Sample input:

```
# (1296) {20} [529] [1496] [411]
# (MONDAY ) (1296)
# (646) {20} (BEACH 7) [20 Mtrs] { 03 Foot }
# {19} [455] [721] (1296) (SUNDAY ) [2741] (MONDAY (WEDNESDAY {20}
# {19} (1296)
```

Code which does not work:

```
$re = '/(?:\[[^][]*]|\([^()]*\)|{[^{}]*})(*SKIP)(*F)|[^][(){}@#]+/m';
$result = preg_replace($re, '', $input);
```

Incorrect output:

```
#(1296){20}[529][1496][411]
#(1296) 
#(646){20}(BEACH 7)[20 Mtrs]{ 03 Foot }
#{19}[455][721](1296)[2741](({20}
#{19}(1296)
```

Desired output:

```
#(1296) {20} [529] [1496] [411]
#(1296)
#(646) {20}
#{19} [455] [721] (1296) [2741] {20}
#{19} (1296)
```

Comment: When I see something like `(MONDAY (WEDNESDAY {20}` I almost want to tokenize using newlines and spaces and inspect each token

Comment: Check [this PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/JmOPv).

Comment: An idea to [replace `((?:\[\d*\]|\(\d*\)|{\d*})\s?)|[^#\r\n]` with `$1`](https://regex101.com/r/C9Px3A/1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could match at least 1 digit between the brackets and then skip that match.

Then match any char except a newline or `#` to be replaced with an empty string.

```
(?:\[\h*\d[\h\d]*]|\(\h*\d[\h\d]*\)|{\h*\d[\h\d]*})\h*(*SKIP)(*F)|[^#\n]
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\[\h*\d[\h\d]*]` Match at least 1 digit between square brackets, where `\h` matches horizontal whitespace characters (no newlines)
  - `|` Or
  - `\(\h*\d[\h\d]*\)` 1 digit between parenthesis
  - `|` Or
  - `{\h*\d[\h\d]*}` 1 digit between curly braces
- `)\h*` Close the non capture group and match 1+ spaces
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` Skip and fail the match (to leave it untouched in the output)
- `|` Or
- `[^#\n]` Match any character except `#` or a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lh0mQP/1)

Answer (score 3):

You may match using this regex:

```bash
(?>(\()|({)|\[)\h*\d[\h\d]*+(?(1)\)|(?(2)}|]))\h*(*SKIP)(*F)|[][(){}]|[^][(){}\r\n#]+
```

and replace with an empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ndWEeg/10)

**RegEx Details:**

```bash
(?>             # Start atomic group
   (\()         # Match ( and capture in group #1
   |            # OR
   ({)          # Match { and capture in group #2
   |            # OR
   \[           # Match [
)               # End atomic group
\h*\d           # Match a digit after 0 or more whitespaces
[\h\d]*+        # Match 0 or more digits or whitespaces
(?(1)           # Condition if capture group 1 is present
   \)           # Match closing )
   |            # Else
   (?(2)        # Condition if capture group 2 is present
      }         # Match closing }
      |         # Else
      ]         # Match closing ]
   )            # End condition of capture group 2
)               # End condition of capture group 1
\h*             # Match 0 or more whitespaces
(*SKIP)(*F)     # Skip and Fail this match that we want to keep
|               # OR
[][(){}]        # Match any of the brackets
|               # OR
[^][(){}\r\n#]+ # Match 1+ of any char not listed inside the [...]
```

Comment: Failed for this input # (1296) {20} [529] [1496] [411] [zz (12) {{45} [monday]

Comment: ok I guess rules were not clear to me. Can `#` appear anywhere else in the line apart from start position? Can `(12` be on first line and `34)` be on 2nd line?

Comment: # will be at start position always, bracket must be closed in same line else to be treated as invalid

Comment: ok got it, answer edited accordingly

Comment: superb, perfect !

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```php
<?php

$s = "# (1296) {20} [529] [1496] [411]\n# (MONDAY ) (1296)\n# (646) {20} (BEACH 7) [20 Mtrs] { 03 Foot }\n# {19} [455] [721] (1296) (SUNDAY ) [2741] (MONDAY (WEDNESDAY {20}\n# {19} (1296)";
if (preg_match_all('~^#|(?:(\[)|(\()|{)\d+(?(1)]|(?(2)\)|}))~m', $s, $m)) {
  echo preg_replace_callback('~^(#)\s*|#\s*~', function($m) { return isset($m[1]) ? "#" : "\n#"; }, implode(" ", $m[0]));
}
```

See [this PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/u8LG5). Output:

```
#(1296) {20} [529] [1496] [411] 
#(1296) 
#(646) {20} 
#{19} [455] [721] (1296) [2741] {20} 
#{19} (1296)
```

*Details*:

- `^#|(?:(\[)|(\()|({))\d+(?(1)]|(?(2)\)|}))` extracts `#` at the start of lines, and sequences of one or more digits inside `()`, `[]` and `{}` brackets
- `implode(" ", $m[0])` - creates a single string with spaces between the found matches
- `preg_replace_callback('~^(#)\s*|#\s*~', function($m) { return isset($m[1]) ? "#" : "\n#"; }` - replaces the `#` and whitespaces at the start of string with just `#`, and all other `#` with whitespaces after them with a newline + `#`.